# Gitlab backup to different servers

Tags: gitlab

I have a gitlab server and would need to create a backup of this server to 2 different servers and both running in different locations, so that in case the main gitlab server is down we can enable any of the 2 backup servers available in different location. Kindly help me if we have any solution to enable the backup as I have free gitlab version.

Answer (score 0):

2022: You have the choice between:

- [automatic backup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_gitlab.html#configuring-cron-to-make-daily-backups) (but you would still need to restore said backup on the original server)
- [HA (High Availability)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reference_architectures/#high-availability-ha), which is closer to what you are looking for.
  It is available for all GitLab tiers, with [instructions here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4811).

---

[GitLab 16.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/10/22/gitlab-16-5-released/#back-up-and-restore-repository-data-in-the-cloud) (October 2023) adds:

> ### Back up and restore repository data in the cloud
>
> The GitLab backup and restore feature now supports storing repository data in object storage. This update improves performance by eliminating the intermediate steps used to create a large tarball, which needs to be manually stored in an appropriate location.
>
> With this update, repository backups get stored in an object storage location of your choice (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, Azure Cloud Data Storage, MinIO, etc.).
> This change eliminates the need to manually move data off of your Gitaly instance.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/backup_restore/backup_gitlab.html#create-server-side-repository-backups) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10826).